# Очевидные решения и лучшие подходы и практики

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

> ### В двух словах
>
> Давайте попробуем расширить кругозор сообщества о существующих прикладных решениях, лучших подходах к программированию и практиках, собрав как можно более объемную базу «очевидных» решений и подходов.

Хотя мы все вроде бы делаем одно и тоже, наш внутренний мир различен, вместе мы дополняем друг друга: каждый из нас привносит в общество что–то свое, логичное, лаконичное и простое для него, но не очевидное для остальных.

Джон Бентли в книге «Жемчужины программирования» рассказывает очень интересную историю о разработке алгоритма поиска максимальной непрерывной последовательности вещественных чисел в одномерном массиве. Он говорит, что если взять простой алгоритм, который требует O(n^3) операций, и попросить разработчиков оптимизировать его, то можно легко увидеть тренд: большинство разработчиков предложат один из двух подходов, оба из которых работают за O(n^2). Причем разработчики поделятся на две группы, каждой из которых «очевидно» лишь одно и только одно решение! Еще более интересным является тот факт, что обыкновенный аналитик решает эту задачу менее чем за минуту *единственно очевидным для него способом* за O(n). Вывод из этой истории, помимо знания самого решения за O(n), которое, на самом деле, дает возможность решать целый класс задач не очевидным для большинства людей способом, в том, что чем больше различных людей высказывает идеи *очевидных для них решений*, тем глубже познания всего сообщества: *очевидное для вас совершенно не очевидно для многих ваших коллег, и наоборот*.

Было бы здорово в ближайшие три зимних месяца вместе сосредоточиться на составлении как можно большего числа «наиболее очевидных» решений по различным аспектам программирования. Так, публикуя вопрос с «единственно правильным» найденным вами решением, вы сможете с удивлением обнаружить, что решений не просто несколько, но и существуют куда более эффективные подходы.

Пожалуйста, публикуйте вопросы с вашими решениями и дополняйте решения, опубликованных вопросов другими! Если каждый из нас поделится чем–то очевидным, наше общее знание станет значительно глубже.

### Как выглядят знания, которые мы ищем?

Рекомендация одна — публикуйте любые прикладные знания, которые вы по тем или иным причинам отметили для себя в процессе изучения: либо подобный вашему вопрос уже есть на сайте, либо его следует задать! Публикуйте вопрос (задачу) с ответом (решением) с особенной уверенностью, если после решения задачи сама проблема вам кажется «тривиальной», а решение «очевидным», хотя до этого вы так не считали.

Несколько примеров:

- «[Глобальные переменные в Python: сохранить локальную переменную от вызова к вызову функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/358/6)».
- «[Что такое абстрактный класс в С++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/170/)»;
- «[Метод equals() в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/439/6)».

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на:

1. Количество просмотров. «Простые очевидные» вопросы крайне востребованы среди наших коллег!
2. Количество и качество ответов, опубликованных в дополнение к имеющемуся ответу от автора вопроса. «Простой» вопрос с «очевидным» ответом обычно можно дополнить очень неочевидной информацией!

### Вопросы, выходящие за рамки технологий и технических проблем: лучшие подходы и практики

Бывает, «очевидные» вопросы несут сугубо прикладной характер, как, например, вопрос эффективного обхода конкретной коллекции на конкретном языке. С другой стороны, у нас есть много прекрасных примеров крайне полезных и популярных вопросов, которые не относятся к технической проблеме как таковой, а скорее *описывают общие подходы, выработанные годами*. Например:

- [«Что такое NullReferenceException, и как мне исправить код?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413041/6);
- [«Для чего нужны свойства?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/197067/6);
- [«Hello world с пустой функцией main»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1811/6);
- и многие другие!

Подобные вопросы учат наших коллег проверенным подходам к реализации, объясняют, каким образом писать лаконичный читаемый код. Они крайне важны и нужны в нашей общей свободной базе знаний сообщества!

### Прикладные вопросы — наше все

Stack Overflow никогда бы не стал тем, чем является, если бы на сайте публиковали оторванные от жизни примеры, сугубо теоретические выкладки или всеобъемлющие абстрактные рассуждения. Пожалуйста, документируйте в вопросах и ответах только реальные ситуации, с которыми вы встретились на практике. Записывайте вопрос в виде проблемы, а ответ — в виде решения.

Например, вопрос, который, вероятно, мало кому поможет, так как его никто не найдет в нужный момент:

> Какой самый лучший способ сортировки листа?

Вопрос, который будет особенно востребован у людей, столкнувшихся с проблемой:

> Как эффективно по памяти и производительности отсортировать список на Python?

Или даже так:

> Как за O(n*logn) отсортировать список на Python без использования дополнительной памяти, превышающей исходный размер более чем в два раза?

<sub>В момент, когда разработчик ищет решение прикладной задачи, в общем случае он нуждается не в самом лучшем способе сделать что–то, а в том, который будет работать в его конкретной ситуации (то есть в ситуации с заданными ограничениями или условиями). Искать решение разработчик будет, именно отталкиваясь от условий конкретной задачи.</sub>

#### Больше, чем просто знания

Stack Overflow на русском – уникальное для Рунета явление: мы ставим взаимное уважение, доброту и человеческое отношение друг к другу во главу угла. Чем больше наше сообщество, тем меньше ругани и злости на просторах русскоязычного Интернета. Чем больше знаний мы даем внешнему миру (людям, не участвующим в жизни сайта), тем больше он, «внешний мир», хочет быть ближе к нам, похожим на нас, то есть добрее и отзывчивее.

### Начнем с себя

Пожалуйста, попробуйте документировать один или два найденных решения в неделю, особенно если они кажутся вам очевидными, в виде вопроса с ответом. Перенося на «бумагу» свои мысли и идеи о решении конкретной задачи или выбранном подходе, можно не только получить критический отзыв извне, но глубже разобраться в проблеме. Не стесняйтесь, дополнять вопросы с ответами других участников вашими мыслями по теме и предпочитаемыми подходами: хотите по–настоящему разобраться в чем–то, попробуйте научить этому других!

И, конечно же, если вы знаете коллегу, который мог бы поделиться с сообществом чем–то «очевидным», пожалуйста, попросите его это сделать! Невероятно приятно, когда к нам присоединяются хорошие опытные знатоки!

### Замечания и предложения

Если у вас есть любые мысли и доводы о том, как улучшить предлагаемую инициативу, пожалуйста, напишите об этом в ответе к этой публикации. Описывая ваше улучшение, добавляйте как можно больше деталей реализации, конкретные примеры и то, как, по вашему мнению, предлагаемый процесс улучшит систему в целом.

Comment: ...если вы хотите поднять количество вопросом с самоответами то очевидным и действенным шагом будет объявить конкурсную неделю и за каждый оформленный вопрос давать поощрительную награду в виде небольшого (например, 50) количества репутации. Дальше соответственно оповестить уведомлением.

Answer (score 2):

Как дополнение, появилась идея. Предлагаю так же создать ветку для новичков (дальше поясню).

Задавать вопросы по типу такого "Как Написать хороший хешкод". С примерами.

Данный вопрос думаю будет безответным, т.к. для каждого есть свой вариант хорошего хешкода. Но на старте своей учебы, я очень хотел видеть не слова "описывайте хороший хешкод, с хорошим распределением по Map и Set", а несколько реальных(не учебных) примеров, возможно с описанием, что стало лучше.

На английском SO по запросу "good hashCode java" выскакивает пачка вопросов с примерами.

---

Итог:

Создавать вопросы, которые людям с опытом кажутся простыми, а для новичков непонятной магией и в ответах приводить практические примеры из жизни.

Comment: Отличный пример! Спасибо! Именно об этом вся инициатива!