# Как мы хотим начать писать Книги сообщества?

Tags: обсуждение, книги-сообщества

<sub>В продолжение инициативы: «[Книга сообщества, или Руководство по изучению технологии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6420/)».</sub>

Я убежден, что мы вместе можем создавать огромную ценность, куда большую, чем каждый по отдельности. Спешу поинтересоваться у вас, каким образом мы с вами хотим подойти к написанию руководств и описанию лучших подходов для наших коллег, как посоветуем приступать к изучению того, что уже знаем мы и чем бы мы хотели поделиться?

*Пожалуйста, подскажите, с чего и как вы бы начали создавать «[руководства](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6420/)» для ваших коллег?*

Было бы очень здорово, если вы поделитесь с сообществом идеями:

#### Что?

- Что бы лично вы хотели увидеть, если бы начинали прямо сейчас изучать что–то новое? Ваш отзыв будет неоценим, если вы действительно начинаете изучать что–то новое, либо недавно изучали, и можете хотя бы примерно описать, в какой форме и какая информация вам бы крайне помогла в изучении.
- Какие знания в вашей конкретной специализации будут особенно полезны начинающим? Какие подводные камни вы видите и какая за ними кроется проблема?

#### Как?

- С чего вы бы начали и как бы построили процессы? Идеально — начать с чего–то реального на сайте, и поделиться с сообществом тем, что у вас получилось, а что вы считаете пустой тратой времени.
- Каким образом вы бы хотели видеть отслеживание процесса написания руководств?

Буду благодарен за любые другие идеи и мысли по воплощению задумки в реальность!

Собрать подобную базу знаний не по силам одному человеку, как и задать оптимальные процессы. Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями по теме, расскажите о ваших подходах к проблеме! Ваши мысли и идеи крайне важны и нужны сообществу!

Comment: "Буду благодарен за любые другие идеи и мысли по воплощению задумки в реальность! " ...донат.

Comment: "Книга сообщества" уже пишется, по сути. Вот например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515309/Исчерпывающее-руководство-по-form-based-website-authentication Лучшие подходы часто представлены в метках [xxx-faq] в виде традиционных вопросов, а базовые понятия - в описаниях меток.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight  Да, это именно то, о чем эта инициатива, возможно, лишь с разбиением таких больших вопросов на несколько маленьких и добавлением прикладных примеров (ссылок на другие вопросы). Как вы можете видеть, вопрос на английском закрыт как «слишком общий».

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight К слову о метках [faq-xxx] и руководствах. Предполагается, что руководство построено на базе faq–вопросов. Руководство раскрывает идею, что и в какой последовательности исследовать, тогда как faq–вопрос — это конкретная проблема с конкретным решением.

Answer (score 5):

## Вопросы-дубликаты

Второй отправной точкой могут стать повторяющиеся вопросы. Если вопрос повторяют, значит он действительно вызывает затруднения. Тонкость в том, что часто дубли появляются когда ТС слабо владеет темой и не "видит" уже готовые ответы. С другой стороны он же что-то сформулировал, значит в чем-то продвинулся, что-то понимает или думает что понимает.

Анализируя вопросы-дубликаты, можно находить эти затруднительные места и уделять им особое внимание при написании руководств.

Вообще, вот с такой аналитикой да еще с обратной связью, можно большие дела делать.

Comment: Думал про дубликаты и общие вопросы. Сейчас анализ сделан на основе того, что спрашивают у нас на сайте. Что скажите, имеет ли смысл делать аналогичное исследование по англоязычному сайту?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Думаю стоит, у них материала то побольше нашего.

Comment: С другой стороны, если опираться только на то, что имеется у нас, мы сделаем только то, что действительно пользуется спросом у русскоязычных разработчиков. Для исследования англоязычной базы вопросов, это уже не верно.

Answer (score 2):

#### «Вопрос слишком общий»

Как мне кажется, данная инициатива имеет огромную значимость для тех, кто только приступает к изучению. Зачастую, на зная как подступиться к задаче и не понимая как описать свою проблему, разработчики задают вопрос достаточно широко, в очень общем и даже абстрактном виде. Такие вопросы не могут получить ответ в рамках Stack Overflow, как минимум, в исходном виде. Как результат, они закрываются как «слишком общие». С другой стороны, для начинающих было бы крайне полезно получить какой–то вектор движения: было бы здорово, если бы мы смогли описать все наши мысли и идеи по теме таких вопросов в рамках правил сайта, и закрывать вопросы как дубликаты, а не общие — и сайт не теряет в качестве, и люди находят то, что искали!

Таким образом, вероятно, *хорошей отправной точкой должны стать вопросы, закрытые как слишком общие*.

На данный момент на сайте было закрыто чуть больше 6 тысяч вопросов, для которых хотя бы один из голосов за закрытие был «вопрос слишком общий». Мы можем проанализировать закрытые вопросы и попробовать вместе создать руководства по наиболее востребованным темам. (Идея структуры самих руководств описана в [исходной публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6420/).)

[Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на проведенный небольшой анализ закрытых вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6524/6).

Answer (score 2):

- Почти для любого дела необходим план работ, для книг это будет содержание.

  - Содержание может выполнять роль "списка-работ", по которым можно отследить ход выполнения.
- Почти в любой области деятельности есть свои специальные термины, которые нужно понимать. Нужен список терминов для данной метки.
- Теория без практики мертва. Нужны примеры (задачи).

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, вам стоит это делать отдельным проектом, который, конечно, может быть в StackExchange, если этого захочет автор.

Полагаю, что если её пытаться вписать в рамки SO, то она не сможет реализовать свой полный потенциал.

Также возможно потому, что эта идея пытается вырасти в рамках SO, она и имеет маленькую поддержку со стороны участников, а где-то даже встречает непонимание.
Думаю, что если это делать отдельным проектом, то желающих будет намного больше. Не будет конфликтов между SO и предлагаемым проектом, и сама идея, и проект смогут свободно вздохнуть.

Comment: Мне кажется, данная инициатива не тянет на отдельный проект. Это, скорее, необходимость реальности: людям, начинающим разработчикам, крайне важно иметь общую базовую информацию, которую в рамках текущих правил и того, как складывается ситуация, нам не собрать. С другой стороны, я не видел более качественного источника знаний, чем сообщество. Одному человеку, такого не написать. Более того, инициатива крайне небольшая: я ожидаю по паре вопросов, с десятком ответов в каждом, для наиболее популярных меток, не более. Начать можно с малого. Главное — начать!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky так давайте начнём, выберем пару тройку меток и для них будем пробовать, потом посмотрим, что будет получаться.

Comment: @edem Отличная идея! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие бы вы метки хотели взять?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky perl и javascript.

Comment: @edem Отлично! Вероятно, смогу как–то помочь только в [tag:javascript] (ни [tag:perl], ни [tag:javascript] не являются теми языками, которые я знаю очень хорошо).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну тогда дело за первоначальным вопросом, в котором будет описана суть и содержание. Кстати, у них будут спец. метки?

Comment: @edem предлагаю метку «[руководство]». Да, первый вопрос. Как мне кажется, тут не стоит усложнять: можно взять [любую подходящую тему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6420/), в которой вы очень хорошо разбираетесь и попробовать изложить ее последовательно. Я постараюсь добавить в нее то, что знаю я, если этих знаний еще не будет в ответе. Было бы совсем здорово, если бы мы смогли построить повествование так, чтобы включить как можно больше [«простых» вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6419/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky 1) Вопросы, ответы, общие, все, не? 2) На одну метку один вопрос и очень очень много ответов или много много вопросов и немного ответов к ним? Как это в плане структуры планируется?

Comment: @edem Как мне кажется, чтобы сделать что–то очень полезное, нам нужен вклад всех участников сообщества: вопросы и ответы задумывались общими. Руководство — это глава книги, где вопрос — содержание, а ответы — параграфы, то есть структура один вопрос — много ответов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил пример по JS https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758847/ но что-то сделать общим не получилось, куда-то пропал checkbox с этой меткой.

Comment: @edem Большое спасибо, сделал общим.