# Анализ вопросов, закрытых как «слишком общие»

Tags: обсуждение, книги-сообщества

**Внимание!** Ответы к данному вопросу созданы программой. Если вы видите недочеты или способы улучшить алгоритм, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или комментарием к [ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6526/6). Пожалуйста, не публикуйте новых ответов в этом вопросе.

---

Данный вопрос призван помочь проанализировать вопросы, закрытые как слишком общие.

#### Основная идея

Выгрузить закрытые вопросы и разбить их на группы, где каждая группа содержит [статистически] схожие вопросы. Анализируя группы, мы вместе, возможно, сможем выбрать несколько наиболее востребованных тем, которые сможем рассмотреть в рамках [руководств для приступающих к изучению](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6420/).

#### Результаты

Данный вопрос содержит 10 ответов. Каждый ответ состоит из одной группы вопросов. Группы расположены по убыванию количества вопросов в каждой. Теоретически, в одну группу входят только статистически похожие вопросы. Код программы разбиения [доступен на GitHub](https://github.com/chabanovsky/too-broad-analysis).

#### Алгоритм

Основные идеи:

- Каждый вопрос является документом.
- По всему набору документов строится словарь.
- Для каждого документа по отдельности строится словарь.
- Для каждого слова в словаре документа рассчитывается частота появления слова в документе (параметр TF).
- Для каждого слова в общем словаре рассчитывается частота его появления в документах (параметр IDF).
- Для каждого документа составляется вектор (массив) слов, где на i-ой позиции находится величина TF * IDF (если слово в документе отсутствует, значение TF равно 0).
- Длина вектора — количество слов в общем словаре.
- Все документы разбиваются на основе косинуса угла между их векторами. Документы в одной группе имеют косинус угла меньше порогового значения по отношению друг к другу.
- На данный момент величина порога 0.91.

#### Что с этим делать?

Если вам знакома какая-либо из тем, представленная в ответах к этому вопросу, пожалуйста, попробуйте написать по ней руководство (вопрос с меткой [руководство](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be)), в котором ответы будут содержать необходимые для авторов вопросов из группы знания.

Дополнительно:

- Список всех закрытых вопросов одним csv-файлом на [GitHub](https://github.com/chabanovsky/too-broad-analysis/blob/master/questions.csv).
- Все группы разбитые по txt-файлам доступны на [сервере](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/groups/).

Comment: Не все из этих вопросов закрыты как "слишком общие". Некоторые не по теме или с непонятной сутью вопроса.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Так и есть. Вопрос попадет в эту выборку если он имеет хотя бы один (из пяти) голос за закрытие как «слишком общий».

Comment: Еще можно дубли анализировать, если вопрос часто повторяют, то видимо по нему больше всего затруднений

Comment: @Cerbo Подумал над вашим предложением и понял, что, видимо, не до конца его понимаю. Пожалуйста, опишите его подробно ответом к [исходному вопросу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6523/6). Пока мысли у меня следующие. Дубли, вероятно, я могу отследить SQL–запросом базе без доп. аналитики. Мы нашли все дубли. Получили список вопросов по убыванию количества обратных ссылок дубликатов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать дальше? То есть вопросы уже такие есть: (1) их можно улучшать, (2) дописать доп. ответы и т.д. Вы это имели в виду или что–то другое?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky не думаю что такие вопросы можно как-то улучшить или дать объективно верный ответ, например "Как писать игры на C++" или "Как попасть в панель управления MySQL?". Их стоит как-то агрегировать и выдать некий список общих вопросов и ответов, например, как вопросы по сбору книг для изучения языков.

Comment: @DaemonHK про улучшение – это о дубликатах. В остальном полностью согласен! Именно об этом данная инициатива.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вы хотите увеличить количество канонических вопросов в метке [книги]? Потому что если один "слишком общий" вопрос  может требовать объёма книги, то группа общих вопросов — уже в целых книжных полках можно измерять.¶ Не вижу что автоматическое разбиение на группы по указанным критериям тут даёт. В качестве альтернативы, можно популярные метки использовать для "слишком общих" вопросов¶ В качестве дополнения к списку книг, можно обновить описание метки [книги] и разрешить ссылки на mind-maps, на программы курсов, другие online ресурсы (уже присутствует в ответах).

Answer (score 1):

Группа №0

- [c++ get-запрос, узнать инфо на сайте](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/753783.txt)
- [C++ в двух словах](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/725941.txt)
- [С чего начать создание игр на C++?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/690691.txt)
- [Как написать шаблон функции для вычисления размера массива C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/682441.txt)
- [Хранение данных, вне программы. С++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/651411.txt)
- [Вставка массива с заданной позиции:](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/644479.txt)
- [цикл for i:=1 to 6 do из паскаля в C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/621352.txt)
- [Переведите пожалуйста с языка C++ на C и если есть ошибки исправьте пожалуйста](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/621348.txt)
- [Задачники по C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/620480.txt)
- [Обход графа в глубину c++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/614417.txt)
- [Как читать предложение в C++?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/613383.txt)
- [начал учить но невыводит](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/603211.txt)
- [Как удалить все слова в строке, которые состоят только из латинских литер?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/597390.txt)
- [Помогите пожалуйста перевести код с C++ на С](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/594817.txt)
- [консольное приложение с++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/579227.txt)
- [Подскажите библиотеку для работы с сетью c++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/578715.txt)
- [Как создать рандом на C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/575156.txt)
- [Пример нейронных сетей C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/575089.txt)
- [Подключение проекта С++ в проект C#](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/561819.txt)
- [Совместимость библиотек между языками](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/541039.txt)
- [Как сделать n копий бинаря программы на c++?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/536606.txt)
- [подскажите как реализовать шаблон класса массив C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/535243.txt)
- [c++,напишите пожалуйста код!](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/528728.txt)
- [Перевести код задачи с C++ на C#](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/514458.txt)
- [Какие способы рисования простых двумерных фигур (окружность, квадрат и т.п.) существуют в C++?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/512077.txt)
- [Перевод из десятичной дроби в цепную](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/500535.txt)
- [Не открывать окно консоли](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/472129.txt)
- [C++ массивы в классах](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/468173.txt)
- [Что входит в стандартную библиотеку C++?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/445258.txt)
- [Сравнение двух строк c++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/417590.txt)
- [C++ для системного программирования](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/352742.txt)
- [Деление переменных в C++ ?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/287331.txt)
- [Какую тему выбрать для курсовой?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/3710.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 1):

Группа №1

- [что мне делать подскажете плис](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/739011.txt)
- [Какой алгоритм использовать для задачи?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/737552.txt)
- [Количество знаний для практической работы на C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/735919.txt)
- [Пример простого класса в C++ (например сложение/вычитание матриц)](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/730533.txt)
- [Что нужно освоить(по порядку),чтобы стать системным программистом и какие качества желательны,а также сколько времени в среднем занимает?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/718911.txt)
- [Дана строка. Определите слово, которое содержит максимальное количество согласные](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/717172.txt)
- [Как программировать микроконтроллеры?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/708349.txt)
- [Сортировать массив строк методом корзинной сортировки](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/647446.txt)
- [применяется ли методика джексона в наше время и где?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/625432.txt)
- [Самые известные методы сортировки](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/63536.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 1):

Группа №2

- [Использование в программе функций C++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/637002.txt)
- [какой смысл аргументов?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/631404.txt)
- [Проблема с массивом](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/627374.txt)
- [Какие отличия функций c++ от функций в c?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/617579.txt)
- [Проблема с циклом c++](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/601371.txt)
- [Вычислить функцию sin через ряд Маклорена(Тейлора)](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/498351.txt)
- [Информация в консоли](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/476093.txt)
- [Для чего нужны классы, если можно все сделать в простой функции? (в C++)](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/401152.txt)
- [Каким кодом C/C++ установить регистры процессора в квантовую суперпозицию?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/309421.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 0):

Группа №3

- [Как сделать мой чат глобальным?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/701328.txt)
- [Искусственный интеллект](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/663359.txt)
- [Javascript выпадающий список](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/633431.txt)
- [Создание окон JavaScript](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/558098.txt)
- [Javascript Возможно ли такое сравнение](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/555736.txt)
- [Что делает данный код?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/547368.txt)
- [Арифметика в JavaScript](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/464567.txt)
- [Самоучители по JavaScript](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/55401.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 0):

Группа №4

- [Зачем нужен язык программирования python](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/749489.txt)
- [Бегущая строка в python 3хх](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/741748.txt)
- [Сортировки python](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/660705.txt)
- [Python 3.5 Два окна](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/567092.txt)
- [Какая из операций изменяет строку s? Python](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/561119.txt)
- [Повторение Python](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/532424.txt)
- [Дайте коммент каждой строчки](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/366648.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 0):

Группа №5

- [Java 9 когда будет релиз](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/717493.txt)
- [Помогите перевести на Java](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/669300.txt)
- [Наставник по Java](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/601399.txt)
- [Как запустить один класс в java из другого класса?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/593975.txt)
- [Видео чат на java](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/565506.txt)
- [Что использовать в качестве суперкласса в Java](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/543111.txt)
- [Как установить, открыть и работать на JAVA?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/73184.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 0):

Группа №7

- [Какой процент пользователей блокирует рекламу в приложениях на Android?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/625698.txt)
- [Как сделать такую кнопку](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/620706.txt)
- [Радио в Android](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/584651.txt)
- [Нужен сервер для приложения под Android](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/582165.txt)
- [Установка Android приложения](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/518699.txt)
- [Реклама в Android приложении](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/454504.txt)
- [Как создать клиент для сайта Android?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/298579.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 0):

Группа №8

- [Ищу хорошую книгу по Mysql](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/589254.txt)
- [Mysql в рhp как настроить?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/568208.txt)
- [Как составить выборку из MySQL?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/534630.txt)
- [Ошибка при запуске MySql](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/444153.txt)
- [Как попасть в панель управления MySQL?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/341118.txt)
- [mysql запрос](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/206374.txt)
- [С чего начать изучение MySQL?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/54424.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score 0):

Группа №9

- [Увеличение производительности android studio](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/752617.txt)
- [Не запускается проект в Android Studio](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/697989.txt)
- [Добавление кнопки в проект, если нет дизайна](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/564648.txt)
- [Как работать с дизайном в Android Studio](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/559446.txt)
- [Компилируется, но не ставится на паузу при привышения лимита паузы)](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/521253.txt)
- [Android studio particle system](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/436364.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.

Answer (score -1):

Группа №6

- [как создать графическую оболочку для рабочего стола](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/666519.txt)
- [Нет звука в Ubuntu 16.04](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/644720.txt)
- [Зависает Ubuntu](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/531837.txt)
- [Crash ubuntu update](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/525918.txt)
- [Как изменить название директорий](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/482149.txt)
- [Взлом пароля, почему  так произошло?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/341457.txt)
- [Как примонтировать диски?](http://assets.rudevs.ru/experiments/too-broad-analysis/questions/340221.txt)

**Внимание!** Это автоматически созданный ответ, пожалуйста, не вносите в него правки.