# Предлагаю оставить по одному вопросу на технологию относительно ее достоинств и недостатков

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

При выборе стека технологий для проекта, если разработчику не с кем посоветоваться, часто идут на SO и задают вопросы подобные этому
[Использовать ли Node.js? Каких трудностей ждать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/986571/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-node-js-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Однако, такой вопрос будет закрыт, т.к. не имеет четкого ответа. Но, я считаю, что этот вполне нормальный вопрос для программиста. В том числе, как и вопрос о материалах для обучения. Поэтому, по аналогии с вопросами про книги и учебные ресурсы,  я предлагаю, оставить по одному вопросу на технологию, в котором бы были ответы относительно ее достоинств и недостатков. Все последующие подобные вопросы закрывать, как дубликаты.
Как-то так.

Comment: Может успеете ответить на вопрос, пока его не закрыли? :) Просто мне сложно представить объективный ответ на такой вопрос. Если у Вас получится, то как раз будет хороший пример в пользу Вашего предложения.

Comment: Прямо сейчас технология X идеальна для проектов типа Y. Через год появится новая технология/библиотека/фреймворк, а эта устареет. По-прежнему будем старый ответ эталоном считать?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, если ставить вопрос: "Что мне выбрать для...", то я с Вами согласен. Но я веду речь о вопросах типа: "Сможет ли технология..."

Comment: В том вопросе очень мало данных. 10000 запросов на сложить 2 числа node  держит не в час, а в секунду. 10000 запросов к базе - тоже должно быть отлично. 10000 запросов на просчёт карты уровня в игре - а вот уже спорно. Хотя в час - это меньше 3 запросов в секунду - да за треть секунды очень многое сделать можно.

Comment: Соглашусь с @AlexanderPetrov На такие вопросы, помимо того, что очень сложно объективно ответить, очень сложно поддерживать в актуальном состоянии, если только ответ не помечен как общий, но и для этого случая необходим "смотрящий".

Answer (score 4):

Такие вопросы действительно не имеют однозначного ответа и поэтому для stackoverflow при текущих правилах это неформат.

Можно ли что-то с этим можно сделать?

Мне кажется, что пару лет назад было [предложение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6419/213987), которое как раз предлагало любопытный вариант решения, фактически реинкарнацию похороненного раздела [документация](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Т.е. вы можете попробовать взять некоторую тему, например, "написать приложение под андроид" и разбить его на конкретные практические вопросы - как писать код, как отлаживать, как составлять схему базы данных и т.п. и оформить отдельной парой вопрос-ответ, возможно связанной кросс-ссылками.

Это "не взлетело", т.к. поднять в одного подобные крупные темы сложно. Что-то подобное описывал Алексей Шиманский в своей серии вопросов, не помню это до предложения было или уже после:

- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/213987)
- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/213987)
- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/213987)
- [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в Javascript коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701137/213987)